# Confusion with automorphisms of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Consider $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ over $\mathbb C$. The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1632670/every-automorphism-of-mathfraksl2-mathbbc-is-given-by-conjugation-with) states that any $\gamma \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ can be written as $x \mapsto g x g^{-1}$ for $x\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $g\in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$. However, take as basis,

$$e= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad f = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad h = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I know we have the conjugation automorphism which is $\gamma(e) = f, \gamma(f) = e$ and $\gamma(h) = -h$ but this cannot be written in the form above. This automorphism has order 2, so $g$ would have order 2 and be diagonal. We also have $\det g = 1$, so
$$g = \begin{pmatrix}
a &0 \\ 
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}$$

such that $ab=1$ and $g^2 = 1$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
a &0 \\ 
0 & b
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a &0 \\ 
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{a}{b} \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ so I can never map $e$ to $f$. I must be misinterpreting something, so where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automorphism $\gamma$ has order 2, but $g$ need not have order 2 and does not have to be diagonal.

Indeed, consider $g = \begin{pmatrix}0 & i \\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}$ or its negation $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ -i & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

---

*Edit*: To be honest, I just solved the system of equations [using SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdzLEOwiAQgOG9Sd_hRqhXAru6O8JKGKi9UpK6IDH69p7EpZ3u8n-Xc-occcI7zle4gLU-9F3i7RFryW_h0Hv2gJ4vQpB9R3vUaBg16obLETWj-eO6R9NQ42ia3lidyjPFTYg0EIywDEmqLT-rkHACjgtHOsaVx7qLPqmZfusIpr1Wr1gy1Y-wdopFfgGqiUHb&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==):

```
sage: R.<a,b,c,d> = QQ[]
sage: g = matrix(R,[[a,b],[c,d]])
sage: e = matrix(R,[[0,1],[0,0]])
sage: f = matrix(R,[[0,0],[1,0]])
sage: h = matrix(R,[[1,0],[0,-1]])
sage: I = R.ideal((g*e - f*g).list() + (g*f - e*g).list() + (g*h + h*g).list() + [g.det() - 1])
sage: I.variety(QQbar)
[{d: 0, c: -1*I, b: -1*I, a: 0}, {d: 0, c: 1*I, b: 1*I, a: 0}]
```

Comment: Oh I see, my false assumption was that $g$ was of finite order 2 (hence why I thought it was diagonal). Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there's some easy way in SageMath to find eigenvectors in the affine sl2 algebra for a particular automorphism?

Comment: I don't know. It sounds like it could be a good separate question, especially when including an example of an automorphism, and (probably) not insisting on the use of SageMath (though it could be suggested).